# Can I change the default forms name template that Django uses?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I know that Django uses default names for it's template engine, for example if I have a Form for Comments Model, Django it's going to search for comments_form.html for render that form. But can I change that? Instead of using comments_form for the form render can I use another html as template? How can I do this using Class Based Views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's very simple.. every Django generic view that displays a template (inherits from `TemplateResponseMixin`), can be told which template to use through the `template_name` attribute:

```
class MyView(FormView):
    template_name = 'myapp/mytemplate.html'
```

This assumes that you are using the standard Django directory layout, eg

```
myproject/myproject/templates/myproject/mytemplate.html
myproject/myapp/templates/myapp/mytemplate.html
```

etc...

You can also modify the template selection behavior of these views by overriding the `get_template_names` method of the view.

The most simple uses of these `TemplateResponseMixin`derived views, such as `TemplateView` and `FormView`, do not have any other way to know what template to use, they require you to either specify `template_name` or to implement the `get_template_names` method, else you will get an exception when you try to access the view.

But the view classes that work with Django models, such as `DetailView`, `UpdateView` etc, are more clever; These classes will look at the name of the model they are told to work with, and derive the name of the template from that, for example:

An `UpdateView` for the model named "Comments" will try to find a template named "comments_form.html", by default.  A `DetailView` will try to use a template named "comments_detail.html"...

So if you follow their convention and name your template the way they expect then everything just works.. it will find your template automatically.  All the other model-oriented view classes (`DeleteView`, `CreateView` and so on) will do this as well.

But you can always override this behavior by using the `template_name` attribute or implementing `get_template_names()`.

Here's the exact section of the Django documentation that may be helpful:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names

Comment: And I need to reference this view in the urls.py?

Comment: Yes, all views need an entry in urls.py to be reachable, that is a separate issue from the template.  Url entry might look like `url(r'^myview/$', views.MyView.as_view(src='tpartner_)`.. but of course if view accepts parameters then this will change the regular expression.

Comment: And for example, if I want this form to be inside a DetailView, the url's are not going to be a problem?

Comment: Sure, all the Django CBV (class based view) classes that display templates use the same code, they'll all honor `template_name`.  Some of those CBV classes REQUIRE you to give `template_name`, for example a simple `TemplateView` has no other way to figure out what template to display.  Other classes such as DetailView and UpdateView which are related to the handling of models will.. if you don't supply `template_name`.. they will try to guess the template name from the model name, as you have seen.. but you can still override it with `template_name`.

Comment: I should say, for a DetailView you need a different URL entry because the url needs to contain the PK (id) of the record that you want to display, so it would look something like `url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.CommentView.as_view(), name='view_comment')`